# get data from the strings.xml

Tags: android

How can I get text from the strings.xml file into my .setmessage?

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
        .setMessage("R.string.erroroik")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can access it through context, depending where exactly this DialogBuilder is, it can be

```
context.getString(R.string.erroroik);
```

or

```
this.getString(R.string.erroroik);
```

Take a look at [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Use `R.string.yourText` without `""` since `R.string.yourText` is referring to an `int` declared as `static` in your `R.java`.

Answer (score 3):

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
                    .setMessage(R.string.erroroik)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Done

Answer (score 3):

The ids in the xml resource files are actually integer values not strings.

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
                    .setMessage(R.string.erroroik)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1

```
Context context;
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
    .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.erroroik))
    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Solution 2

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
    .setMessage(getString(R.string.erroroik))
    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

String x= getResources().getString(R.string.xxxxx);